# Django select indirectly related with a condition

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

In my project, I have `Users` and they can have a certain role. However, the roles are limited by date ranges, that is a user can have an admin role from 01.01.2020 to 02.02.2020, and an unprivileged user role from 02.02.2020 to 03.03.2020.

I need to be able to return the list of users with their current roles and I want to be able to make just one query to the database. However, I can't figure out how to do that.

Here are my models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...

class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class UserRoleQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def current():
        return self.filter(period__contains=date.today())

class UserRoles(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='roles')
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role)
    period = DateTimeRangeField()

    objects = UserRoleQuerySet.as_manager()
```

I need a queryset with either a `prefetch_related`, `select_related` or `annotate` method called on it so that when I then do something like code below, I don't get additional database trips:

```
users = User.objects.(some_magic_here).all()
for user in users:
    print(user.role)
```

*UPD:* To be more specific, if I don't do any annotations, prefetches or select_related, I will get a printout of all (current) user roles. However, each iteration will hit the db to select that current role. What I want is that same printout, but without additional roundtrips to the db

Comment: Give a result for what you want

Comment: @kyore Added the update. I am currently looking at something like this: .extra(select={'monthly_fee':'mobile_subscription.monthly_fee'})

Comment: As I understand you want each of the item of queryset with user's current role names?

Comment: @kyore I want the whole related Role object, but the name would also do

Comment: I think thats not possible with one query. `User.objects.prefetch_related('roles__role')` is hit db 3 times and all other access is free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a set of objects you will need `prefetch_related`, although you cannot alter (filter) the query after the prefetch as Django won't be able to do the join. So you will need to provide the filter when Django is doing the prefetch:

```
users = Users.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'roles',
        queryset=(
            UserRoles.objects
                .filter(period__contains=date.today())
                .select_related('role')
        )
    )
)
```

When you iterate through `users`, again if you alter the query it will take one extra hit to the database per iteration, so instead of doing:

```
for user in users:
    print(user.roles.first().role)
```

you will need to do something like the following to avoid further queries to the database, knowing `user.roles.all()` will always give you only one result:

```
for user in users:
    for user_role in user.roles.all():
        print(user_role.role)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But that still hits the db once per each user in the iteration.

Comment: Can you see what it is querying?

Comment: Updated the reply with "select_related" on the queryset in Prefetch. Now it works. Thanks )